# Resque Scheduler: The highlighted jobs are skipped for current environment. Production Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, procfile, resque-scheduler

I am trying to get my application to work in production.
I have a background job set up and a static scheduler (resque and resque_scheduler). The worker and queing on localhost works without any problem. On heroku the job shows up in the resque_scheuler we UI but is never processed. It says "The highlighted jobs are skipped for current environment.". The job is marked yellow as you can see in the picture.
[image: scheduler web ui with highlighted worker]

This is my job, scheduele and procfile

tweet_sender.rb (job)

```
class TweetSender
    @queue = :tweets_queue 

    def self.perform(tweet_id)
        @user = User.all
        @user.each do |u|
            current_user = u.id
            twt = Tweet.where(user_id: u.uid).where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first
            if twt
                twt.status_id = 1
                twt.save
                client = u.twitter_client_from_user
                client.update(twt.text)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

tweet_schedule.yml

```
tweet_sender:
  every:
    - "30s"
    - :first_in: '10s'
  class: "TweetSender"
  queue: tweets_queue
  args: tweet_id
  rails_env: development
  description: "This job sends daily tweets from the content db"
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 COUNT=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work 
worker: bundle exec rake environment=production resque:work COUNT=1 QUEUE=*
scheduler: bundle exec rake environment=production resque:scheduler
```

I have looked through the documentation but could not find any explanation. Does anybody know why this job is highlighted and how to get it to scheduele.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set your `tweet_schedule.yml` job as running only on `rails_env: development`. To let your job run in multiple environments(let's say production too), you have to set it to `rails_env: development, production`

```
tweet_sender:
  every:
    - "30s"
    - :first_in: '10s'
  class: "TweetSender"
  queue: tweets_queue
  args: tweet_id
  rails_env: development, production
  description: "This job sends daily tweets from the content db"
```